# possible to detect click on an element using a greasemonkey-type user script?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Let's say I have a greasemonkey-type user script running on a page that has a div such as:

```
<div id="watchme">something</div>
```

Is it possible to detect if a user clicks on that div from within the user script?  The logical way would be to have an onClick() written into the code, but since this is a user script I don't control the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try attaching an event listener?

```
document.getElementById("watchme").addEventListener("click", yourHandler, false);
```

Note that assigning the `onclick` method may not work: see [this.](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.232%3a_Event_Handlers)

Comment: hm... interesting read, but the author did not address anonymous functions.  any ideas on why an anonymous function works and a function reference does not?

Comment: indeed, Joseph's suggestion for onclick works great from the console, but does not work when run as a greasemonkey script.  the addeventlistener does the trick, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("watchme").onclick = function(){
    alert("I've been clicked");
}
```

That's how you assign the onclick event in js.